# Как перенастроить репозиторий с github на bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Я свой проект заливал на репо GitHub. Потом пришлось оттуда удалить. Нужно было залить на BitBucket. Но когда я заливаю, Git выдает **ошибку:**

```
Push failed
app\src\main\java\kz\tem_tour: push to origin/master was rejected
Project: failed with error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user_login/project.git/' not found
```

Может, остались какие-то файлы Гитхабовские или тексты?

Что неправильно делаю, как очистить?

Comment: Как push делаете? У вас origin на github указывает. Попробуйте `git remote remove origin; git remote add origin <bitbucket_url>`

Comment: на вкладке VCS > Import Into Version Control > Share Project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

этот адрес указан в конфигурации вашего репозитория. т.е. в файле `.git/config`. скорее всего, примерно так:

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/user_login/project.git/
...
```

можете вручную исправить этот файл, вписав нужное значение. а можете с помощью команды указать *url* созданного вами репозитория на сайте *bitbucket.org*:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/...
```

Comment: В какой папке находится этот файл ? Вообще нигде не могу найти этот git config

Comment: в каталоге вашего проекта должен быть каталог `.git`, а в нём файл `config`.

Comment: @Omuradil но лучше, пока не освоитесь, не меняйте ничего руками в папке `.git`. Используйте команды git, например вышеупомянутую `git remote set-url`.