# Залить репозиторий с Bitbucket на Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Добрый день. Склонировал с Bitbucket чужой репозиторий, внёс некоторые свои изменения и теперь хочу залить всё в новосозданный свой репозиторий на Github. Помогите с последовательностью действий.

Comment: Ещё вот это вам понадобится: [Как перенастроить репозиторий с github на bitbucket?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502132/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-github-%d0%bd%d0%b0-bitbucket)

Comment: Вы будете в дальнейшем вливать к себе новые изменения из оригинального репозитрия?